# Microphone permission on Oculus Quest

Tags: android, permissions, microphone, oculus

I am developing android application or Oculus Quest.
When we install app by apk, it goes into Unknown Resource, not Application.

In Permission management tab, they only show a list of Applications (not include Unknown resource app).

As a result, even I requested Microphone permission successfully, it is unmanaged and CAN NOT record audio.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: This is self-fixed by latest upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.I wanted to use Azure SpeechToText in Unity 2019.3.7.

According to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html

> Unity automatically adds the necessary permissions to the manifest
> based on the Android Player Settings and Unity APIs that your app
> calls from the script. For example:
>
> - The Microphone class adds RECORD_AUDIO
> - Network classes add the INTERNET permission

So, to enable bot network and microphone I added

```
Debug.Log(Microphone.Devices.Length);
Debug.Log(Application.internetReachability.ToSTring());
```

in one of the Start() methods, and it worked